# Batch file creation

Tags: redirect, batch-file, file-io

I have two exe's. Each exe is having two arguments, one is input and the other is the output. I need to create a batch file using these two exe's such that the output of the first exe is the input for the second exe. 
As a user, I should give input filename of the first exe and output filename of the second exe

Comment: post your code created so far

Answer (score 0):

Lets assume that you have the following files: Input.dat, 1st.exe, Transitional.dat, 2nd.exe, Output.dat. They should be launched in the manner:

```
1st.exe Input.dat Transitional.dat  
2nd.exe Transitional.dat Output.dat
```

Right?
If so, all you have to do is to create ouptut file in the system tmporary folder and delete it before the end:

```
1st.exe %1 %TEMP%\Transitional.dat  
2nd.exe %TEMP%\Transitional.dat %2  
del /y  %TEMP%\Transitional.dat
```

If, however, your 1st.exe is a command line application that dumps the result onto screen instead of file, you have to redirect it into a file:

```
1st.exe %1 > %TEMP%\Transitional.dat  
2nd.exe %TEMP%\Transitional.dat %2  
del /y  %TEMP%\Transitional.dat
```

The user has to call this batch as follws:

```
BatFile.bat Input.dat Output.dat
```

Is this anything close to your answer?